# VirtualBox initialization got error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox in my laptop with Ubuntu 10.04 installed. Everything run well until one day, i start VirtualBox with my guest OSs: WindowsXP/CentOS and get this error:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> Please install the virtualbox-ose-dkms package and execute 'modprobe
>   vboxdrv' as root.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `vboxdrv` module is not signed and therefore not loaded with the kernel. This will happen if your computer has the SecureBoot mode activated, something very common in modern equipment.

That's why I get this error opening any machine in the Virtual Box

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Do the following steps to sign a driver, and it is loaded as a kernel module, on Ubuntu systems and also on Debian 9:

**1.** Install the `mkutil` package to be able to do signed.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mokutil
```

**2.** generate the signature file:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VirtualBox/"
```

**3.** Then add it to the kernel:

```
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vboxdrv)
```

**4.** Register it for the Secure Boot.

**IMPORTANT!** That will ask you for a password, put the one you want, you will only have to use it once in the next reboot.

```
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

**5.** Finally, restart the computer. A blue screen will appear with a keyboard wait, press the key that asks you to interrupt the boot.

[image]

When you are inside the blue screen, select

```
Enroll MOK > Continue > Yes > and it will ask you for the password
```

that you have previously entered, you will enter it and you will be informed that the operation has been completed successfully.

Now your operating system will start and you can now use VirtualBox without problem :)

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

The system is telling you to run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-dkms
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

from a terminal window.

Did you recently do an `apt-get upgrade` and grab a new kernel or something?

Comment: I installed virtualbox-ose-dkms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191968/cannot-install-virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms-on-ubuntu-10-04