# The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DfEF.png)

i followed the steps on [Sign virtual box modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) Centos 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248315/sign-virtual-box-modules-vboxdrv-vboxnetflt-vboxnetadp-vboxpci-centos-8) and it worked. But after shutting down my pc for the night and turning it back on I have now received the issue again, it seems it only lasts after the first restart. Is that because im on fedora? Help me please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: When you ask elsewhere, don't  post images of code or errors. Include exactly what you did, in the question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Just try to install the development tools and the kernel headers again:

```
$ sudo dnf -y install @development-tools
$ sudo dnf install kernel-headers kernel-devel dkms  -y
```